# Is there an easy way to trigger a hoverenter/hoverleave event on children of a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

For styling purposes, I'm trying to make all the widgets in a set of widgets adopt a certain background if a pointer enteres any of those widgets;
i.e. if the pointer is insides the containing rectangle of widget A, both A and widget B should change its background. Likewise if the pointer enters B, then A should also adopt the same background. The background should, naturally, fall back to the non-hovering background if the pointer is outside both A and B.

QWidget appears to have most of the plumbing to get this done, but its hidden behind `protected`.

I really want to avoid inheriting from QWidget if I can avoid it and I really would like to not have to change the stylesheets of the widgets too.

[1] In my case, I have three widgets, not two.

Comment: To handle events on a widget without sub-classing it you can use event filter approach: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) class, and let it hold the affected widgets in a vector of pointers:

```
#include <QMouseEvent>

class EventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QVector<QWidget*> widgets;

public:
    void append(QWidget * w)
    {
        w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
        w->installEventFilter(this);
        widgets.append(w);
    }
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->type() == QMouseEvent::HoverEnter)
        {
            for(auto w : widgets)
            {
                w->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
            }
        }
        else if(event->type() == QMouseEvent::HoverLeave)
        {
            for(auto w : widgets)
            {
                w->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The `append` method will set up the widget and push it in the vector.

Have a private filter instance in your form class:

```
class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    //...

private:
    EventFilter filter;

   //...
```

In your form constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

filter.append(ui->widget1);
filter.append(ui->widget2);
filter.append(ui->widget3);
```

In the example I used `setStyleSheet` to set the background color, but you can use whatever strategy you prefer, i.e. resetting the widget palette.